# Remove part of filename with common delimiter

Tags: linux, bash, rename

I have a number of files with the following naming:

```
name1.name2.s01.ep01.RANDOMWORD.mp4
name1.name2.s01.ep02.RANDOMWORD.mp4
name1.name2.s01.ep03.RANDOMWORD.mp4
```

I need to remove everything between the last . and ep# from the file names and only have `name1.name2.s01.ep01.mp4` (sometimes the extension can be different)

```
name1.name2.s01.ep01.mp4
name1.name2.s01.ep02.mp4
name1.name2.s01.ep03.mp4
```

Comment: BTW, http://www.filebot.net/

Comment: I am delete my answer for now, cause i no really understand the question ...

Comment: @FrankAK It's very clear that `RANDOMWORD` should be removed from the filename...

Comment: Please update the question with what you've done so far to achieve your ob.

Comment: `fName=name1.name2.s01.ep03.RANDOMWORD.mp4 ; fName=${fName%.mp4} ; fName=${fName%.*}.mp4; echo New fName=${fName}` Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simpler version of [@Jesse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5055577/jesse)'s [[answer]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48179675/1620779)

```
for file in /path/to/base_folder/* #Globbing to get the files
do
 epno=${file#*.ep}
 mv "$file" "${file%.ep*}."ep${epno%%.*}".${file##*.}"  
 #For the renaming part,see the note below
done
```

---

<sup>**Note** : Didn't get a grab of shell parameter expansion yet ? Check [[ **this** ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).</sup>

Comment: Sorry, it does work! Can you please expand the answer to remove multiple RANDOMWORD. It removed all single instances, but if there were multiple ones it left untouched. e.g. dance.hall.s01ep01.tom.is.on.fire.mp4. In this example .tom.is.on.fire would need to be removed

Comment: The downvoter please tell me why the downvote on this one? Huh?

Comment: For multiple random words, this approach will not work. You need a more fine-grained text-manipulation tool.

Comment: My apologies, i did it prematurely but i can upvote after answer is modified. stackoverflow wont allow me to upvote now if the answer isnt modified.

Comment: @Andy Oh! That is okay pal ! No issues. :-) But just one more question to see if i could be of any help.. Does the word just before multple random words follow some pattern?

Comment: Yes, it indicates season and episode and its standard across all files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162858/discussion-between-andy-and-sjsam).

Comment: @Andy I have incorporated some changes to deal with multiple random words..It should work fine now.. Waiting for the upvote pal ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Using Linux string manipulation (refer: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) you could achieve like so:

You need to do per file-extension type.

```
for file in <directory>/*
do
        name=${file}
        firstchar="${name:0:1}"
        extension=${name##${firstchar}*.}
        lastchar=$(echo ${name}  | tail -c 2)
        strip1=${name%.*$lastchar}
        lastchar=$(echo ${strip1}  | tail -c 2)
        strip2=${strip1%.*$lastchar}
        mv $name "${strip2}.${extension}"
done
```

Comment: But, I have a feel this can be made simpler ;-)

Comment: Most definitely. It's a question of whether it's worth the time/effort in making it so

Comment: Hmm. I agree. Also you may change `Linux String manipulation functions` to `Linux Shell Parameter Expansion`. The former is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rename` (you may need to install it). But it works like `sed` on filenames.

As an example

```
$ for i in `seq 3`; do touch "name1.name2.s01.ep0$i.RANDOMWORD.txt"; done
$ ls -l
name1.name2.s01.ep01.RANDOMWORD.txt 
name1.name2.s01.ep02.RANDOMWORD.txt
name1.name2.s01.ep03.RANDOMWORD.txt
$ rename 's/(name1.name2.s01.ep\d{2})\..*(.txt)$/$1$2/' name1.name2.s01.ep0*
$ ls -l
name1.name2.s01.ep01.txt     
name1.name2.s01.ep02.txt     
name1.name2.s01.ep03.txt
```

Where this expression matches your filenames, and using two capture groups so that the `$1$2` in the replacement operation are the parts outside the "RANDOMWORD"

`(name1.name2.s01.ep\d{2})\..*(.txt)$`